# Call garbage collect in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, garbage-collection, visual-studio-2015

Is it possible, to say the gc to collect during debugging session via Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise?

I want to observe the memory usage of my application when calling `GC.Collect()`, but only for some debugging reasing. So calling it from Visual Studio during debugging the app would be very helpful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What kind of data? Why would the GC be responsible for collecting any kind of data? Are you wanting to view the GC calls? Have you looked at the performance analyzing tools in visual studio?

Comment: This sounds like an X-Y problem. Are you having a particular issue that you need to resolve?

Comment: Sorry for the bad fomulation, i will correct the question.

Comment: Be careful :) You can have different results depending on whether you are running a debug or released version of your program.

Comment: Thank you for that information. Currently reading: http://www.markfalto.com/Blog/post/Garbage-Collector-behavior-differences-in-Debug-vs-Release-mode.aspx

Comment: This is very intresting: `The trick lies in the fact that in debug mode objects are artificially "rooted" for you throughout the scope of a single method.  This means any objects declared in a method will not be GCed until the method goes out of scope.  In release mode they can be GCed as soon as the last line which uses them executes`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can write `GC.Collect()` in the *Immediate Window*.

Comment: Just a hint: In later visual studio editions there is no immediate window anymore. You can achieve the same by pressing "Break" while debugging and typing `GC.Collect()` into the watch window.

Comment: The Immediate Window is available from the **Debug | Windows | Immediate** menu item. Ctrl + Alt + I

Answer (score 7):

During a breakpoint you can use the "immediate window" to issue commands, just do a `GC.Collect()`

Answer (score 7):

You can use the Visual-Studio Shortcut for Tools.ForceGC:

Press `Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F12, Ctrl+Shift+Alt+F12`

Doku and more Shortcuts for VS 2015 see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx

Solution found here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/camerons/2010/12/15/force-vs-to-garbage-collect/

Comment: AFAIK this only calls the GC for the Visual Studio process, not the one you are debugging.

Answer (score 1):

Put a breakpoint in your code. When execution reaches the breakpoint, in Immediate Window run System.GC.Collect();
You can see in Diagnostic Tools that Garbage Collection was applied.